# How to search data in mysql database and add the search data in DataGridView using C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, search, datagridview

I am working on it for an hours now maybe 6 hours i can't get it working please tell me what is missing?

So for Example I have here client Warren Buffet (he is just an example :D) if i search his name on the txtbox and sqldatabase find his name on the data row then Wafrren Bufet Data will be added to the DataGridView.

Here's the code!

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = null;
            string hostname = "localhost";
            string database = "aparece_hoteldb";
            string username = "root";
            string password = "";
            connection = new MySqlConnection("host=" + hostname +
                                            ";database=" + database +
                                            ";username=" + username +
                                            ";password=" + password + ";");

            string query = "select * from reservations " +
                           "where Client like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' OR " +
                               "ClientNumber like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' OR " +
                               "RoomNumber like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' OR " +
                               "ClientRoomType like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' OR " +
                               "AddonService like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' OR "+ 
                               "TotalHotelRate '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'";

            connection.Open();
            List<string>[] detailList = a.mysqlSelect(query);
            for (int i = 0; i < detailList.Length; i++)
            {
                dgvUser.Rows.Add(detailList[i][0], detailList[i][1], detailList[i][2], detailList[i][3], detailList[i][4]);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Here's the image!

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: the purpose of this function incase the database will become loaded with datas I can still locate the name of the client.

Comment: Sorry for repeating codes I will edit them later using OOP the important now is I will make it working!

Comment: So far the datagridview above is perfectly working just below it isn't working!

Comment: Hi! I shorten the code above to make it more understandable!

Answer (score 0):

So you mean there are already data in the DataGridView and if you search a using TextBox, it will be added on the list on the DataGridView? Here's my code:

```
var detailList = (a.mysqlSelect(query)).ToList();
foreach(var dList in detailList)
{
   dgvUser.Rows.Add(dList);
}
```

But if you want to to only have the data search on the DataGridView, here's my code:

```
var detailList = (a.mysqlSelect(query)).ToList();
dgvUser.DataSource = detailList;
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT:
And by the way, your code in query lacks a "like" in the TotalHotelRate.